# VLookup Between Date And Time With Head

Tags: excel, excel-formula

Hi Experts I Need Help I Want Output Need Below Mention Picture
I add Text Start Date And Date After I Found In This.

[image]

[image]

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

=IFERROR(INDEX(Input!D:D,MATCH(output!B2,Input!C:C,0)),"")